# RxJava2 Flowable.create blockingSubscribe semantics with BackpressureStrategy

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I'm having some difficulty understanding how the Flowable BackpressureStrategy works with the blockingSubscribe method - or it seems unexpected to me and would appreciate if someone could explain it to me.

I was testing this code in the `FlowableTests` file in current trunk.

```
@Test
public void testCreateBackpressureDrop() {
    Flowable.create(new FlowableOnSubscribe<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(FlowableEmitter<Integer> e) throws Exception {
            e.onNext(1);
            e.onNext(3);
            e.onNext(4);
            e.onComplete();
        }
    }, BackpressureStrategy.DROP).blockingSubscribe(w);

    verify(w, times(1)).onNext(1);
    verify(w, times(1)).onNext(3);
    verify(w, times(1)).onNext(4);
    verify(w, times(1)).onComplete();
}
```

If I use `subscribe(w)` and `BackpressureStragegy.DROP` or `Backpressure.BUFFER` the test passes.  However if I use `blockingSubscribe(w)`, `Backpressure.BUFFER` passes but `Backpressure.DROP` fails saying the `onNext(1)` was never called.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical problem with using Mockito to mock a `Subscriber`: you have to call `request(N)` in its `onSubscribe`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> Subscriber<T> mockSubscriber() {
    Subscriber<T> w = mock(Subscriber.class);

    Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock a) throws Throwable {
            Subscription s = a.getArgument(0);
            s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            return null;
        }
    }).when(w).onSubscribe((Subscription)any());

    return w;
}
```

The complication with `blockingSubscribe` is that it executes the `w.onSubscribe` above after the `FlowableOnSubscribe` has run.

Comment: Is it expected that `s.request(N)` is called in the `onSubscribe` in normal code (non-test code)?  Is there any helpful documentation around this yet?  Thanks!

Comment: If you implement it via `Subscriber` then yes. `DisposableSubscriber` and `ResourceSubscriber` do it for you. If you are familiar with RxJava 1, then see https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0 . Otherwise there are blogs about RxJava 2 here and there.